# retrieving .json object and storing it in variables

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

My .json file is:

```
{
"links":[
  {source: "algorithms cormen", target: "irodov", type: "default"},
  {source: "algorithms cormen", target: "skienna", type: "default"},
  {source: "irodov", target: "skienna", type: "default"},
  {source: "irodov", target: "algorithms cormen", type: "default"}
],
"data":[
    {node: "algorithms cormen", data: "bible of algos"},
    {node: "irodov", data: "bibile of physics"},
    {node: "skienna", data: "cool book"}
]
}
```

Now in my javascript file, I want the data stored by "links" to go to a links variable. The same thing I want to do with the "data"
How do I achieve this? I am using d3.js library, so if there is some function included in this library which I can use, mention them.

Comment: `var links  = JSON.parse(yourjson).links`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

update the json file to (assuming you are including the json file on page load not via ajax)

```
var json-data = { 
     "links":[
         {source: "algorithms cormen", target: "irodov", type: "default"},
         {source: "algorithms cormen", target: "skienna", type: "default"},
         {source: "irodov", target: "skienna", type: "default"},
         {source: "irodov", target: "algorithms cormen", type: "default"}
],
    "data":[
        {node: "algorithms cormen", data: "bible of algos"},
        {node: "irodov", data: "bibile of physics"},
        {node: "skienna", data: "cool book"}
    ]
}
```

then to access

```
var links = json-data.links; 
var data = json-data.data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just parse the JSON and assign the value to variables:

```
var json; // I am assuming this is populated with your JSON string
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(json);
var links = jsonObj.links;
var data = jsonObj.data;
```